# Does Internet Explorer have a timeout setting?

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic

We have a Legacy web page that takes more than an hour to load (yes I know that is horrible). The header and navigation links/buttons display, and then Ajax begins to load content. At the 1 - 1.25 hour mark Internet Explorer 10 stops loading, what has been displayed is no longer visible, and the body of the page is the generic "This page can't be displayed". Server-side is ASP Classic on Windows Server 2012.

IIS logs don't show any errors for the request(s), and IIS is setup to send errors to browser and server-side debugging is enabled. IE has "show friendly errors" unchecked. The Windows event log does not show any warning, error, or critical events for any of the "IIS" or "Active Server Pages" sources.

The same page (same revision of code and binaries from our subversion) runs on my own development machine without error using IE 11.

Any thoughts on what might cause this? To me it looks like a client-side IE timeout.

I tested with Chrome. Although the page takes 1.4 hours to load, it does load without error.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article to check the **KeepAliveTimeout** value of IE: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/813827/how-to-change-the-default-keep-alive-time-out-value-in-internet-explor. You can also use F12 to check if there's something wrong when the page loading in IE. Check the requests in Network tab using F12.

Comment: The Developer Tools window just says the request is "Aborted". But it's not aborted by server-side. The keep alive must be working, else the web server would drop the request long before an hour elapses.

Comment: What kind of content that your page has? Is it any data, images or video or heavy graphics?If you are trying to load very heavy page then it can be possible that IE meets with its limitation. I suggest that making your page as light as possible.

Comment: The page content is text only. Although there is a lot of it, rendered in a table (which IE is slow to render to begin with).

Comment: I haven't met a page takes such a long time to load. I think you should try to optimize the page first and making it loads faster.

Comment: We don't want to spend much time on it. We're trying to push out version 2 of our software, and get rid of the badly-written legacy stuff. Part of the problem is the amount of records (tens of millions), and the crazy logic they want applied to the data.